# Magento 1 Custom form validation is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, form-validation

I try to validate my form but it doesn't work and i don't know why. Please help me to find problem. Thanks

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('vendor/addproduct/new') ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="form-validate" name="form-validate"
  class="scaffold-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="field name-name">
        <label for="<?php echo $login->getData("name"); ?>"
               class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Name') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('name') ?>" 
                   name="name"
                   value="<?php echo $login->getData("name"); ?>"
                   title="<?php echo $this->__('Name') ?>" maxlength="255"
                   class="input-text required-entry"/>
       </div>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //< ![CDATA[
    var customForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Try this way http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2016/04/12/magento2-form-validation/ it will help you.

Comment: @ChiragPatel Is there a similarity between magento 1 and magento 2?

Comment: I am not sure about Magento 1 but it's working for magento 2

Comment: still does not work

Comment: Update above your code, so will go through it.

Comment: please check the console log.

Comment: @kunj After check console log, i searched on google for that errors then i added jQuery.noConflict(), and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Great!, welcome please add your solution as answer and accept it so it will help to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your validate not work, try to add jQuery.noConflict()